# "Order by" no me ordena por todos los campos filtrados

Tags: php, mysql, ordenamiento

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos a la que realizo una consulta general, pongamos:

```
select * from archivo
```

Ahora bien, necesito que los resultados se ordenen, en primer lugar por palet, luego por calle, fila, piso... lo que transforma la consulta en esto

```
select * from archivo order by palet desc, calle asc, fila asc, piso asc
//(sí, los campos deben llevar esa ordenación ASC, DESC variable)
```

Pero los resultados no salen ordenados tal como se solicita, únicamente ordena por el primero de los campos filtrados (palet desc)

```
palet   calle lado         Fila   piso  ubicacion   pegatina
------  ----- ---------    ----   ----  ----------  ----------
LIBROS  F     IZQUIERDO     13      2   E           PF1132
754     G     DERECHO       12      3   D           PG2123
753     G     IZQUIERDO     1       3   A           PG1013    
752     G     IZQUIERDO     8       3   C           PG1083
751     F     IZQUIERDO     11      3   D           PF1113
750     F     DERECHO       15      4   E           PF2154
746     F     IZQUIERDO     10      3   D           PF1103
745     F     IZQUIERDO     10      3   D           PF1103
```

Hay que decir que todos los campos, excepto el de piso, son campos de texto pero entiendo que aun siendo texto debería ordenarlos no?

Comment: ¿Porque dices que no están ordenados? no hay dos `palet` con el mismo valor, así que el resto de la ordenación es irrelevante. Añade registros con valores iguales para observar el comportamiento de la ordenación.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu consulta te está devolviendo los valores ordenados por la primera consulta, debido a que cada resultado se obtiene por filas.
Cada fila posee un grupo de elementos los cuales no se pueden separar, por ejemplo:
Si creamos una tabla con personas con los siguientes datos:

```
fecha_nacimiento nombre apellido
---------------- ------ --------
1987-07-09       Jorge  Zarco
2018-01-01       Juan   Perez
1987-07-09       Jorge  Campos
1987-07-09       Pedro  Paramo
1754-04-08       Carlos Segundo
```

Al hacer consultas sobre esta tabla no será posible ordenar por más de un elemento a menos que existan elementos repetidos, en este caso si ordenamos por "fecha y nombre y apellido", la consulta ordenará todas las filas por la fecha ya sea ascendente o descendente, después de esto, si existen fechas repetidas (1987-07-09), ordenará dentro de esas fechas repetidas los nombres repetidos y así sucesivamente, quedando como resultado:

```
fecha_nacimiento nombre apellido
---------------- ------ --------
1754-04-08       Carlos Segundo
1987-07-09       Jorge  Campos
1987-07-09       Jorge  Zarco
1987-07-09       Pedro  Paramo
2018-01-01       Juan   Perez
```

En el caso de tu consulta, al ordenar por el campo palet y no existir ningún elemento repetido, se descartan los demás campos en el ordenamiento de la consulta.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @Cristian. Estoy bastante boba porque no me dí cuenta que no repetía palets, de hecho, estaba obcecada con que debería ver primero todas las filas que tuvieran el lado derecho y luego todas las del izquierdo, ignorando por completo el campo del palet que resulta el principal.

He hecho una pregunta estúpida :(

Comment: La pregunta tiene una buena exposición del escenario con los datos necesarios para que podamos ayudarte; por "sencilla" que sea no se puede considerar mala, sobre todo si las respuestas te han ayudado a entender el problema.

Comment: Estoy contigo @PabloLozano, se entendió rápidamente el problema porque la pregunta está formulada de una forma clara. Ojalá todas las preguntas tuvieran ese estilo, a veces el OP termina aclarando el problema después de 10 ó 15 comentarios, a veces después de una larga conversación en el chat.